# Would Lasagna be a non-Newtonian substance?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, non-newtonian-fluids

I was having a random discussion with some work colleagues, and we stumbled across the subject of lasagna (the dish, not just the noodles) being a non-Newtonian substance.

My argument was that you could probably run across the width of a swimming pool full of lasagna, but standing in one place, you would sink - thus proving that it is in fact a non-Newtonian substance. This is probably because one of the ingredients in lasagna is typically cornstarch.

One of my colleagues says I'm a madman, and I must go back to school to learn physics properly.

So - is it a non-Newtonian substance? Why or why not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67794/discussion-on-question-by-john-bell-would-lasagna-be-a-non-newtonian-substance).

Comment: It wasn’t exactly a lot of comments so do you think moving it to chat was entirely necessary?

Comment: Yes, I do. Keep in mind that comments are meant for suggesting improvements to the question, including by requesting clarification or linking to related resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking whether a bowl or plate of lasagna exhibits rheological behavior essentially identical to that of a newtonian fluid (even on a scale large compared to the sheets of pasta), then the answer is no.  If you are asking whether the experiment you describe is capable to resolving the issue as to whether it is a Newtonian fluid or not, then the answer to that is also no.  It is possible to conceive of a purely Newtonian fluid that has such a high viscosity that you could run across a pool full of it without sinking in, while, if you stood in one place for a long enough time, you would sink in.  So your proposed experiment is incapable of resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you for confirming I am a mad man and should go back to school.

Comment: Now I wish I knew more about delicious rheology.